# invalidChannelId when using YouTube API V3 search with forMine=true

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I try to get my last 10 videos, this request is generated by the Google APIs explorer :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But I have an error response :

```
"domain": "youtube.search",
"reason": "invalidChannelId",
"message": "Invalid channel.",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "channelId"
```

I don't understand, because the documentation explains that you have to choose forMine=true OR filter for a channelId. But not both.

I have the same error if I try the request below, found in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#search) :

```
GET {base_URL}/search?part=snippet
                     &forMine=true
                     &order=viewCount
                     &type=video
```

Just follow the link and authorize requests give the same error without changing anything.

What do I wrong ? Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a standard call to it.
Reason is, is that this call to the api is requiring authorisation.

As example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?access_token=[access_token]&part=snippet&mine=true
```

Info can be found [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) regarding Oauth2

As well as you need to see if using the "search" parameter is really the best choice for your needs. As it has a high quota count.